# How to make text do not appear outside of div?

Tags: html, css, frontend

I've tried setting overflow to hidden, word-wrap to break-word and text-overflow ellipsis to a paragraph, the div wrapping the paragraph and the div wrapping the before mentioned div.

```css
.card {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 50px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* or `pre` */
  overflow: hidden;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.background-image {
  width: 100%;
}

.content {
  margin: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* or `pre` */
  overflow: hidden;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

h1,
p {
  margin: 0;
}

.rating {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.star {
  width: 20px;
}

.average-rating {
  position: absolute;
  right: -30px;
  top: 59px;
}

.rating-count {
  position: absolute;
  top: 59px;
  right: -72px;
}

.secondary-title {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.text {
  margin-top: 20px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* or `pre` */
  overflow: hidden;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <img src="background.jpg" class="background-image" alt="card-background">
  <div class="content">
    <h1 class='title'>Title</h1>
    <div class="rating">
      <img src="star.png" class="star" alt="Star rating">
      <img src="star.png" class="star" alt="Star rating">
      <img src="star.png" class="star" alt="Star rating">
      <img src="star.png" class="star" alt="Star rating">
      <img src="star.png" class="star" alt="Star rating">
      <p class="average-rating">4.5</p>
      <p class="rating-count">(413)</p>
    </div>
    <p class="secondary-title">Secondary title</p>
    <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You do not want `.text` to appear outside of which div? Is it `.card`, `.content` or `.rating`?

Comment: @Learning Mathematics outside of content, but also card because they are the same width

Comment: @GucciBananaKing99 i am using that on all - on paragraph, the wrapping div, and div that wraps the div.

Comment: You can remove `position: absolute;` in  `.content`. Does that achieve what you want?

Comment: I made this an answer. Please consider accepting it if it helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As position absolute will take `.content` out of the document flow, it will no longer take up any space like what a normal div will do. So the space taken by `.content` is not limited by `.card` anymore, resulting in no word wrapping. Therefore, removing `position: absolute` will do the job. I removed several css properties that are unnecessary for your purposes and here is the code:

```css
.card {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 50px;
  /* or `pre` */
}

.background-image {
  width: 100%;
}

.content {
  margin: 20px;
  /* or `pre` */
}

h1,
p {
  margin: 0;
}

.rating {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.star {
  width: 20px;
}

.average-rating {
  position: absolute;
  right: -30px;
  top: 59px;
}

.rating-count {
  position: absolute;
  top: 59px;
  right: -72px;
}

.secondary-title {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.text {
  margin-top: 20px;
  /* or `pre` */
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000" class="background-image" alt="card-background">
  <div class="content">
    <h1 class='title'>Title</h1>
    <div class="rating">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" class="star" alt="Star rating">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" class="star" alt="Star rating">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" class="star" alt="Star rating">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" class="star" alt="Star rating">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" class="star" alt="Star rating">
      <p class="average-rating">4.5</p>
      <p class="rating-count">(413)</p>
    </div>
    <p class="secondary-title">Secondary title</p>
    <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor</p>
  </div>
</div>
```